# How to force an Azure WebApp to restart after each deploy?

Tags: azure, web-applications, deployment, azure-resource-manager, restart

I have a Web Application (Java) running on Azure. Every time we deploy it (via ARM template deployment) we have to restart it manually to make it work. Is there any setting to restart it automatically after each deployment?

SOLUTION:
Just added a Azure Powershell task at the end of my relase pipeline with the command:
Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name xxx

Comment: The main question is WHY should it be necessary that your app needs restart after a new deploy? I would think that the whole bottomline of ARM is precisely to create immutable infrastructure by means of desired state configuration. When you deploy an arm template, it should take care of everything, no?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an ARM configuration to automatically restart the app after the deployment. However, you could consider using the [`Restart-AzWebAppSlot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/restart-azwebappslot?view=azps-2.0.0) PowerShell cmdlet after your deployment to restart it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It was not the solution, but it pointed me to the correct direction. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We use the Azure CLI version

```
az login ...
az webapp restart --name "${{ env.WEB_APPNAME }}" \
    --resource-group "${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME }}"
```

Agreed it should not be necessary, or the action itself should support a "restart" command.